# kivy apk loose sqlite when upgrade

Tags: sqlite, kivy, apk

I build an apk with kivy and buildozer, it use sqlite db. Everything works fine, but when i apudate the apk, it loose the db. How to keep the db when update the apk?

I try to save in another folder...